# drying out a shower leak

Tags: drywall, shower, leak

I had a leak in my shower. The caulk on the interior of the shower had failed. I cleaned and replace the caulk, and as far as I can tell, there is no more leak.

I'm now trying to repair the water damage to the area on the exterior of the shower. I cleaned out the discolored joint compound covering (roughly in the area circled in red below) and let it dry for a couple days. I then tried covering the area with new joint compound to prep for painting, but within an hour, I saw more discoloration.  (The discoloration pattern corresponds to the gaps in the curved vinyl bullnose underneath. **EDIT**: I added an Image 4 showing what it looks like after sanding.)

I repeated the removal and drying process again, and when it happened again, I thought I needed to do a more complete dry-out of space inside the wall.  And that's where I possibly made a bad error.  I cut a hole in the drywall (the green arrow in Image 1, closeup in Images 2 and 3), and I apparently cut through something that might be the shower pan liner? I wasn't expecting the liner to be immediately on the other side of the drywall, so maybe it's something else?  We've taken multiple showers since and I don't see any water accumulating anywhere in this area.

Bottom line, I'd welcome thoughts on:

1. How do I more completely dry out the leak area, and
2. What do I need to do to repair my hole (aside from drywall patch).

**Image 1: Shower exterior**:
[image: Shower exterior]

**Image 2: Closeup of discoloration**:

[image: closeup of discoloration]

**Image 3: Closeup of hole in drywall**:

[image: closeup of hole]

**Image 4: Closeup after sanding**:
[image]

Comment: Image 3, is your humidity barrier, not bad, yo can replace that pice

Comment: Image 1- insert a lath horizontal or vertical that is longer that the hole. Screw it with screws. Not you can screw the pice of drywall to it so it will hold.

Comment: Image 2-- try to sand it off

Comment: Thank you! After I sand off the discolored area, how long do I need to wait before building it back up? I waited a couple days last time but the discoloration came back within an hour of applying new joint compound. Does that mean there's still moisture behind here?

Comment: It could be rusting screws or nails

Comment: I'm pretty sure the discoloration aligns with the gaps in the bullnose corner bead -- I added an Image 4 showing what it looks like after sanding.

Comment: You are right. Now use a heat gun and dry as much as you can

Comment: got it, will give a heat gun a shot. thanks!

Comment: Great, I gave you some + points for been cooperative and posting many photos.

Comment: @Ruskes how about posting answers instead of comments. That allows the system to work properly, allowing others to up/down vote the answer as a whole. Unfortunately, no, you're not the only one who's been doing this lately. :(

Comment: https://www.kilz.com/company-overview

Comment: A few sessions with the heat gun has definitely helped dry that area out. Only a tiny bit of discoloration bleeding through now, so I think it'll be all good with one more round. @Ruskes if you want to create an answer that references this comment thread, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again! (I still have a question about patching that hole, but will move that to another post...)

Comment: @Andrew done happy it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a heat gun you can accelerate the drying.

Do not hold it too close so not to create burn marks on the drywall.

It might take a while so have patience.